# "Last Activity" in Moderator Tools → History is incorrect

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

When I look at [the "history" tab of the moderator dashboard on Meta.Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/admin?filter=all), my row in the table lists my last activity as being on "Jul 1 at 9:41".

[image: irrelevant details removed]

However, if I [click on that link](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/history/13), I see this:

[image: irrelevant details removed]

Clearly, I have had activity more recent than Jul 1 (the "14 hours ago" one has a timestamp of "2014-07-07 21:57:12Z").

I presume this is not a caching issue, given that I would expect the caches to not last in excess of 14 hours.

Comment: "I would expect the caches to not last in excess of 14 hours" Every time I assumed something similar, it turned out I was wrong. /just saying...

Comment: @Yannis #cacheing

Comment: Maybe it means last time you did some moderator action?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, I wasn't even a moderator on July 1, so that would be weird. (Also, the items in my second screenshot are all moderator-only activities.)

Comment: Oh, missed it's a brand new site. Hmm... not really caching, more like missing synchronization is likely the issue.